# System freezes on disk I/O

Tags: freeze, disk

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and since few weeks (I cannot say when exactly), my system is experiencing freezes when there are disk I/Os.

My system is installed on an ext4 partition of a SSD.

Even if the load is not very high, some short freezes occur, mouse moves are no longer smooth, Plasma is responding slowly, apps are often in "waiting for disk" state.

This happens for any kind of disk use : software launches, file transfer. When the system starts swapping, it becomes almost unusable.

There is no error in SMART report and I am using Windows on the same disk without anything comparable, so it should not be a hardware problem.

I have checked the partition offset and changed the IO scheduler (https://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2010/08/28/Solving-Linux-system-lockup-when-intensive-disk-I/O-are-performed), and it remains the same.

I have the impression that it is linked to the interruptions management, but I don't know how to check that.

I am now running out of ideas and I hope you may help!

**EDIT:**

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60           #default
```

free -h (at startup)

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        780M        1.6G        117M        1.4G        2.6G
Swap:          3.7G          0B        3.7G
```

I found a repeatable way to create this freeze with a partition scan with GParted. At startup there is no problem but freezes seem to appear when the first bytes are written on swap. I am checking my swap configuration.

**EDIT 2:**

The problem appears very quickly. With this memory usage, it is already freezing:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        1.7G        530M        267M        1.5G        1.5G
Swap:          3.7G         48M        3.7G
```

Comment: Why ext3 partition, instead of ext4? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: This is a mistake, the partition format is ext4 actually! My post have been edited

Comment: Temporarily try `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80` and see if things improve. If they do I'll show you how to make that setting permanent. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: What apps do you have open when you start to see the problem? Show me `free -h` again after the problem begins. What processor do you have?

Comment: Show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema That happens when I am using a web browser or IDEs which are my main apps.
The IDEs I use are quite heavy and I often need more than 3GB over the 4GB my laptop has, so changing swappiness would not affect this I think.

And my laptop has a very basic configuration with Intel Core i3-4030U

Comment: re:"so changing swappiness would not affect this I think"... but you came here for help, yes? Reboot, and try my temporary setting, and let's see what happens. Ultimately you probably need to add more RAM.

Comment: remember to show me the `ls` command, but please place the output as an edit to your question... not into the comments, please.

Comment: @heynnema Unfortunately, changing the swappiness maybe delayed but did not removed the problem.
I am using Plasma as desktop environment so the folder you ask for does not exist.

Comment: Did you reboot before the vm.swappiness change? Try vm.swappiness=90 then. Report back.

Comment: How many tabs do you normally have open in Firefox? Do you have any extensions installed there?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I always reboot to test your tips, and it is still the same with swappinness=90.
I usually have up to 15 tabs in Firefox but for the tests, there is only one.
This may not be clear but this problem appeared randomly (probably with an update) and my system had not this behavior on the fresh installation.

Comment: Although I strongly suspect that more RAM would solve the problem, why don't you try a newer kernel? I normally don't recommend that, but you can always go back if it doesn't help. Go to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/ and download the 4 needed files to get 5.5.6. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema That worked! I am surprised but my PC behaves now correctly with the new kernel... I do not know what caused the problem but this is a satisfactory fix. Thank you fo your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

After playing around with vm.swappiness=80, we decided to try a newer kernel. We downloaded 5.5.6 from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.6/, and so far the machine is working fine!

Ultimately, based on the user's normal apps, Firefox with 15 tabs, and an IDE, more RAM might very well be needed. Install RAM in matched pairs of equal type/size RAM to take advantage of memory interleaving. *ie: 2 x 4G RAM, or 2 x 8G RAM.*

Answer (score 0):

(low reputation doesn't allow commenting...)
Ever found a way to mitigate this? Seems like it describes this same issue I'm having on Debian.

I'm also having I/O Disk problems in Debian. It's so weird because I don't even know how to describe the issue, is difficult searching for solutions when you don't know what exactly to search.
It seems like there are other people using Debian complaining about severe I/O problems as well. (for years too)
Something is "locking up" the entire I/O system.

I don't suffer these problems in Manjaro, could you make a test in Manjaro to see if it behaves differently there? (so we can be sure that it's an issue with Debian itself)

In my case, it's Cities Skylines, a C#/DotNet application that is having issues (DotNet games will claim all your memory and swap space regardless of the amount you have)
Screenshots with more detail for context:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDXtP.jpg
It would be nice if someone knew of command-line launch parameters that I could use with C# applications in order to make more tests, or to somehow limit the amount of disk threads it needs. The disk seems to be overwhelmed with requests, it looks like that.