# System freezing on disk I/O

Tags: ssd, freeze, disk, io

I am facing a similar (maybe the same problem) reported by [System freezes on disk I/O](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212736/system-freezes-on-disk-i-o/1323830#1323830) . This problem also occurred with the first release of Fedora 36.

When I start a process a little more disk I/O demanding, all aplications freeze and the light of disk keeps in a constant full brighteness for seconds or even minutes. Simple tasks, like copying [a 200 MB directory] or unzipping files (using graphical interface or terminal), are sufficient to trigger the problem. This happens even when using the shell in the recovery mode.

I tried both available scheduling options of disk I/O, mq-deadline (default) and none.

My config:

- Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15.0-37-generic)
- i7 9700k
- 16 GB de RAM
- RTX 2070
- SSD Kingston A400

```
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       1,6Gi        11Gi        88Mi       2,2Gi        13Gi
Swap:          2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
...
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6174
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1145
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
167 Write_Protect_Mode      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 SATA_Phy_Error_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
169 Bad_Block_Rate          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
170 Bad_Blk_Ct_Erl/Lat      0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 MaxAvgErase_Ct          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       201
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   073   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 26/73)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 CRC_Error_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   095   095   000    Old_age   Offline      -       95
233 Flash_Writes_GiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7968
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4379
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2333
244 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       53
245 Max_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       153
246 Total_Erase_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       37087
...
```

```
# gdisk /dev/sda
...
Model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
...
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2000895   976.0 MiB   EF00  
   2         2000896         6000639   1.9 GiB     8300  
   3         6000640       937701375   444.3 GiB   8300
...
```

Edit:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   1,6G  3,6M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt  437G  297G  118G  72% /
tmpfs                   7,8G  127M  7,7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2               1,9G  244M  1,5G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1               975M   33M  942M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs                   1,6G  2,4M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: How full is the drive? SSDs slow down considerably when they are very full

Comment: @Esther I added the information to the question. The root partition has 28% (118G) of free space at the root mount point/home directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing my setup with a HDD, noticing that the read speed was normal and taking into consideration @Esther comment on the question, I finally solved it.

Looks like it was the Luks2 encryption. It encrypts the entire disk (partition) and the SSD can't distinguish between free and used sectors, so it can't use the trim feature (from what I understood).

[Enabling trim on luks2](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2021/11/23/enable-trim-on-external-luks-encrypted-drive/) partition did the trick:

`# cryptsetup --allow-discards --persistent refresh <mapping_of_the_encrypted_drive>`

If you want give it a try, keep in mind the following [security warning](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html):

> WARNING:  This  command  can have a negative security impact because it can make filesystem-level  operations  visible  on  the physical  device.  For example,  information leaking filesystem type, used space, etc. may be extractable from the physical device  if the discarded blocks can be located later. If in doubt, do not use it.